# Raspberry real-time line charts

Tags: charts, raspberry-pi, real-time

I'd like to build a display for live-data of rounds per minute.
The graph should update 60/s and show only the last 30 secs or so.
it's although okay to write code by myself, but what library should be used with with language?

So the question is with which tools it is possible to achieve this?

Comment: I think more info is needed to answer properly... Where is this chart meant to be displayed? On a website? On a TFT screen connected to the Pi? Somewhere else? Also, how are you getting the data? Via serial? From log files? JSON? From some other source?

Comment: So Data source is not defined yet. I have to read the data from a BT Dongle, but I can save them as needed.
The Display should be a tft screen ~800*600.

Answer (score 0):

If the display is a LCD monitor connected to Raspberry Pi directly (that is, via HDMI), you may consider to use Raspbian as OS, and use C++ as the language and   Qt as the GUI framework. The Qt framework has a QChart Class for plotting charts. There are also third party C++ charting libraries available that works on the Qt framework (such as ChartDirector). However, I am not sure if Raspberry Pi is fast enough to plot 800 x 600 at 60 frames per second. You can  obtain data at 60 values per second or faster and store the data, and update the screen at a slower rate. For your information, a DVD movie is only 24 frames per second and it is already quite smooth to me.